# How to use a Double variable within sql statement in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to update an sql column to show the percentage by dividing a column of real type (Amount) by a variable of double type (Total) which is calculated earlier and has a value, however I am confused how to write the statement.

Below code gives an error saying no column with name Total exists which is a value not a column!

Thanks in advance.

```
SqlCommand percent = new SqlCommand("UPDATE QuantitiesTable SET percgrosvol = (Amount/Total)", ccn);

percent.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: then you need to make total a parameter..... otherwise how would it know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a variable `Total` in your C# code and you want to pass it to the query.

Then, you just need to pass the parameter value to the command:

```
SqlCommand percent = new SqlCommand("UPDATE QuantitiesTable SET percgrosvol = Amount/@Total", ccn);
percent .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", Total);
percent.ExecuteScalar();
```